# How to execute click event from javascript code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using the `bootstrap-vue` collapse component.

```html
<!-- https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse -->

<b-button-group>
  <b-nav-item
    class="mr-2 mr-md-0"
    link-classes="py-2 px-3"
    :active="true"
    v-b-toggle.my-collapse
  >
    <span class="d-none d-md-block">Filter</span>
    <span class="d-md-none">F</span>
  </b-nav-item>
</b-button-group>
```

This is my collapse element:

```html
<b-collapse id="my-collapse" class="col-lg-12">
  <b-card class="col-lg-12">
    <b-form @submit.prevent="onSubmitFilterCard">
      ...
    </b-form>
  </b-card>
</b-collapse>
```

Inside the collapse I have a form, and when I submit it I also want to close the collapse. How can I execute the toggle from the code instead of clicking on the "b-nav-item"?

Comment: Try this https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse#v-model-support

Comment: use event.preventDefault() for more info.. google it.

Comment: Using this code -> this.$root.$emit('bv::toggle::collapse', 'my-collapse')